# Node.js GraphicsMagick not working ( Invalid Parameter - -resize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

I am trying to use [Graphics Magick](https://aheckmann.github.io/gm/) to resize an image. I have installed the latest [GrapchicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) versions. I have installed

```
 npm install gm
 npm install im
```

too. **My node.js code is:**

```
  var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});

  var srcPath = __dirname + '\\' + userId + '.jpg';
  var dstPath = __dirname + '\\' + userId + '-thumbnail.jpg';

  gm(srcPath)
  .resize(100, 100)
  .noProfile()
  .write(dstPath, function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('Image resized');
    else console.log(err);
  });
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
 Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -resize
```

I am using Windows 10 and I installed .exe and npm too.

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: I think you should install im from website not from npm.

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Try insalling from this web : https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved. I had to copy the identify.exe to my app folder.